# spring jpa - inheriting entity does not get its own id column

Tags: java, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have an entity `HygieneItem` inheriting from `Item`.

```
@Entity
@Table(name="hygieneitems")
public class HygieneItem extends Item
{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "hygieneitem_id")
    private long id;

    @Column(name="retailer")
    private String retailer;
    // getters & setters
}

@Entity
@Table(name="items")
@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
public class Item
{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "item_id")
    private long id;

    @Column(name="item_name")
    private String itemName;
    //getters & setters
}
```

but the `hygieneitems` table uses the `item_id` instead of its own `hygieneitem_id`

```
Hibernate: create table hygieneitems (item_id bigint not null, item_name varchar(255), cart_id bigint not null, retailer varchar(255), primary key (item_id))
Hibernate: create table items (item_id bigint not null, item_name varchar(255), cart_id bigint not null, primary key (item_id))
```

In the [jpa documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnbqn.html) I just read

> [...] InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS, each concrete class is mapped to a separate table in the database. All fields or properties in the class, including inherited fields or properties, are mapped to columns in the class’s table in the database.

How can I tell JPA that it should give the `hygieneitems` table its own ID column along with the columns defined in `HygieneItem` and in `Item` (apart from the `item_id` column)?

The project can be found on [github](https://github.com/MaxHoefl/springboot-jpademo)

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot override the id in an inheritance hierarchy.

So the primary key @Id is always defined in the parent class.